# Probability of difference of uniform distributions smaller than zero

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, computational-mathematics

Let's say I have $N$ independent uniformly distributed random variables $U(a_i, b_i)$ and I'm interested in
$$P(U_1 - U_2\cdots - U_N < 0) \text{ .}$$

How would I calculate something like that? I'm assuming expression above means that $U_1$ ends up being smaller than all of the other variables. There are trivial cases where $b_1 < a_i$ but for the overlapping distributions it looks hard to calculate.

I do know that a difference $U_i - U_j$ is a triangular distribution, so I could just calculate the area of the triangles/squares but with more variables in the difference the calculation gets too complicated.

Comment: The variables are independent, I presume...

Comment: @DiegoG7 Yes they are independent.

Comment: Ok (better to make it explicit in the text). I suspect that the solution is very involved, not for conceptual reasons, but because the problem is very generic: any $N$ and al different intervals $(a_i,b_i) $. I would suggest to start with a particular case: $N=3$ and equal intervals $(a,b)$

Comment: Note that if $\sum\limits_{i=i}^n a_i > a_1+b_1$ then your probability is $0$ while if $\sum\limits_{i=i}^n b_i < a_1+b_1$  then your probability is $1$